# Create function which sorts 2 given sorted strings

Tags: c

Given two **sorted** strings, I need to merge these strings to one string, and make it sorted.
**sort by the ASCII value**. for example:
`acdty`, `berz` => `abcdertyz`

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* PairSortedArrays(char a[], char b[]) {
    char* c = (char*)malloc((sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)) * sizeof(char));
    int i, aPos = 0, bPos = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(*c); i++) {
        if ((int)(a[aPos]) <= (int)(b[bPos])) {
            c[i] = a[aPos];
            aPos++;
        }
        else {
            c[i] = b[bPos];
            bPos++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s", PairSortedArrays("acdty", "berz"));
    return 0;
}
```

The first problem is with `sizeof(a)`. if I code: `printf("%d", sizeof(a));` it prints `8`, while I expect it to print `5`.

Comment: `char a[]` as function parameter is adjusted to `char *a` so `sizeof(a)` gives "size of pointer" as opposed to "size of array".

Comment: `char* c = (char*)malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b));` You'll need to add 1 for the null character. And don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: @dandan78 I used strlen.. but still.. there is a problem as described

Comment: You're lucky. It *could* be printing "segfault".

Comment: Please don't edit the code in your question to eliminate problems. This makes it very difficult for people who come along later and read the question and comments to understand what's actually going on. I've rolled back to the last version of the question which contained `sizeof`. Thanks.

Comment: Tal Rofe, given "sort by the ASCII value", what should happen when the values are outside the ASCII 0-127 range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `i < sizeof(*c)` controling the `for` loop is the main culprit. The corrected version of your program could be: (I edited the code a bit)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* PairSortedArrays(const char a[], const char b[])
{
    size_t i;
    const size_t total_len = strlen(a)+strlen(b);
    char *c = malloc(total_len + 1);
    size_t aPos = 0, bPos = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < total_len; i++) {
        if (a[aPos] == '\0') {
            strcpy(c + i, b + bPos);
            break;
        }
        if (b[bPos] == '\0') {
            strcpy(c + i, a + aPos);
            break;
        }
        c[i] = a[aPos] < b[bPos] ? a[aPos++] : b[bPos++];
    }

    return c;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", PairSortedArrays("acdty", "berz"));
    printf("%s\n", PairSortedArrays("az", "ks"));
    return 0;
}
```

The return value of `malloc` must be checked against NULL in a real program. Also there is a memory leak (easy to fix).

Comment: Doesn't work with `PairSortedArrays("az", "ks")`. It returns `aks` instead of `aksz`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Copied from the original code. Fixed now. I wouldn't myself use indexes; I would use just pointers `a` and `b`, but I didn't want to edit the original code much.

Answer (score 1):

When working with strings in C, you will want to be using `strlen()` to see how long they are, not `sizeof` (which merely tells you what the size of a pointer is).

Also note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so there's no need to say "`* sizeof(char)`" in your `malloc`

Comment: `sizeof` tells you the size of object or type, depending on its operand.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(a)` will return the size of a pointer in this case which will be 8 bytes if you compile for 64 architecture.
you have to either pass the size of each string or loop the string characters until you reach the `'\0'` if the string is null-terminated.

Comment: A _string_ is null-terminated _by definition_.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `qsort`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare_chars(const void *p1, const void *p2)
  {
  return *(const char *)p1 - *(const char *)p2;
  }

char *PairSortedArrays(char *a, char *b)
  {
  char *c = malloc(strlen(a)+strlen(b)+1);

  strcpy(c, a);
  strcat(c, b);

  qsort(c, strlen(c), sizeof(char), compare_chars);

  return c;
  }

int main()
  {
  printf("%s", PairSortedArrays("acdty", "berz"));
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: True, but that increases the run-time complexity from O(n) to O(n log n).

Comment: As Grandma Roseannadanna once said, "It's always something!" :-)